# Where Windows 8 store data of things I recently changed?

Tags: windows, windows-restore

Today when I start my computer I see it's not start successfully and show me somthing to Restore like option.

I click it and it's rollback many things I have done in my past. suppose.

1.I have uninstalled the software in last days. I have seen them in add or remove option and it's finally work now.  (How a software can come back which I have uninstalled).

2. I can see that my email adress which I have removed are come back. My firefox (latest Beta) goes downgrade. I have installed update in last days and now I can see it's goes downgrade.

So where they stored all thing which they have rollback.I am sure if they have make a software installed once again which I have already uninstalled then they have stored it somewhere.

so Where Win8 store these files which I have restored.

Comment: They restore the files where they were, you rolled back your system, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you had System Restore enabled, it would have automatically created restore points before major changes to the system. You can also choose to create restore points manually whenever required. Read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Restore) for more details about this feature.

[image: 1]

When you rolled back, you ended up with the state of the system restored to the snapshot last taken.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/zxue/windows-8-how-to-29-restore-system-to-a-previous-state-using-restore-point) another Windows 8-specific System Restore article.